# Install GNU Scientific library (GSL) on Ubuntu 14.04 via terminal

Tags: 14.04, command-line, software-installation

I am trying to install [GSL](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/) libraries on Ubuntu 14.04 via terminal. I searched on Google but I couldn't find any command which can install it from the terminal but just through the Ubuntu software center. How can it be installed via terminal?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The GSL [source package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/source/trusty/gsl) provides the following binary packages:

- [gsl-bin](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gsl-bin): GNU Scientific Library (GSL) -- binary package
- [libgsl0-dbg](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgsl0-dbg): GNU Scientific Library (GSL) -- debug symbols package
- [libgsl0-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgsl0-dev): GNU Scientific Library (GSL) -- development package
- [libgsl0ldbl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libgsl0ldbl): GNU Scientific Library (GSL) -- library package

To install the library package, open a Terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0ldbl
```

Comment: What's the difference between the different packages? Should I install `gsl-bin` or `libgsl0ldbl`?

Comment: @becko: It depends on your needs, install `gsl-bin` as it will install both (`gsl-bin` depends on `libgsl0ldbl`)

Comment: @becko it really depends on your needs. If you only install/run some programs that requires gsl, then `libgsl0ldbl` should suffice. If you develop/compile some other program that requires `gsl`, `libgsl0-dev` could be required.

Comment: @HongboZhu And what about `gsl-bin`?

Comment: @becko `gsl-bin` contains pre-compiled binaries , which also uses the library `libgsl0ldbl`. The shared library is combined with the binary if it is only needed by the binary. Otherwise they are separated (as in this case). It is very likely that the gsl routines compiled in `gsl-bin` are required. So why not start with `sudo apt-get install gsl-bin`

Answer (score 19):

The packages for GSL can be found [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gsl)
You can install just the library by using:
`apt-get install libgsl0ldbl`

You can also install the development package and binary using:
`apt-get install gsl-bin libgsl0-dev`

The resources/docs can also be installed using:
`apt-get install gsl-doc-info gsl-doc-pdf gsl-ref-html gsl-ref-psdoc`

*depending on your setup you may need to use `sudo` before the `apt-get` command