# What is wrong when I install GSL in ubuntu 16.04LTS?

Tags: package-management

I want to install GSL library. There is a link previous on this topic:
[Install GNU Scientific library (GSL) on Ubuntu 14.04 via terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/490465/install-gnu-scientific-library-gsl-on-ubuntu-14-04-via-terminal)

But I have such message when I install it.

```
8500:~$ sudo apt-get install libgsl0ldbl

[sudo] password for jeff: 

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

Package libgsl0ldbl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

However, the following packages replace it:
  libgsl2 libgsl2:i386
```

---

I also check this link: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gsl
but I don't know what procedures to download the package.
Could you tell me the detail steps to download/install GSL?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I *think* that the answer is simply `sudo apt install libgsl2` (i.e. there is no longer a separate long double precision package). What are you installing it *for*?